# How to move image across JPanel in Java?

Tags: java, swing, animation

I am trying to get the image move from left to right. I thought incrementing the x position in the run method could achieve this but the image just moves all over the panel. What concept am I missing here?

Here is my code below:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Races extends JFrame
 {
//Global variables
Icon imgPacman;
JLabel lblPacman;
JSeparator finishLine; 
RaceThread pacmanRace;
Thread tRace;

 int screenWidth;
 int screenHeight;

 public Races()
 {
    initialize();
 }

 public void initialize()
 {
  //Initial frame setup
  this.setTitle("Races");
  this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

  //Image          
  imgPacman = new ImageIcon("races.gif");
  screenWidth = imgPacman.getIconWidth() * 20;
  screenHeight = (int) (imgPacman.getIconHeight() * 1.8);

  pacmanRace = new RaceThread(imgPacman);

  //Thread
  tRace = new Thread(pacmanRace);
  tRace.start();

  //Final frame setup
  this.add(pacmanRace);
  this.setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
  this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  this.setVisible(true);
 }

 protected class RaceThread extends JPanel implements Runnable
 {       
  Icon aIcon;
  int racePos;

  public RaceThread(Icon _aIcon)
  {
     aIcon = _aIcon;
     this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.orange));
  }

  public void run()
  {
     int waitTime = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
     while(true)
     {
        repaint();
        racePos++;         
     }     
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
     racePos = 0;
     aIcon.paintIcon(this, g, racePos, 0);
  }            
  }//end of inner class


 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  new Races();
 }

}//end of class
```

Please keep in mind I'm a beginner with Java graphics...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Don't use `paint`, use `paintComponent`
- Call `super.paintComponent` before doing any custom painting or you will suffer from a number of paint artifacts and shadowing
- Consider using a `javax.swing.Timer` instead of a `Thread`.  Updates are triggered within in the Event Dispatching Thread, reducing the risk of thread contamination
- Paint methods are for painting, don't update the state of the component from them.  For example, remove `racePos = 0;` from you paint methods and initialise it else where.

Take a look at:

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

For more details

Answer (score 1):

I would start by removing `racePos = 0` from paint and initializing that in the declaration or constructor, as `repaint()` calls the `paint()` method, constantly setting `racePos` to zero.

try setting `y` to something other than zero, because your image might be getting rendered off of the screen. `JFrame` axes start on the top left, not on the bottom left.